# How to iterate the guzzle response

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting a guzzle response from an api request. Any idea how to iterate the response so I get the duration text and value. here is my response. I have tried to foreach but doesnt work:

```
array:1 [▼
  "elements" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "distance" => array:2 [▼
        "text" => "293 mi"
        "value" => 470780
      ]
      "duration" => array:2 [▼
        "text" => "4 hours 50 mins"
        "value" => 17411
      ]
      "status" => "OK"
    ]
  ]
```

this is how I get this json

```
 $items = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)['rows'][0];
        dd($items);
```

Comment: Show your code?

Comment: check it now @JonStirling

Comment: So the output you've shown is from the `dd`? Can you also show the foreach you say isn't working?

Comment: yeah thats the output basically. hmm I will add it in a minute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The response is encoded as `json`, so to use it you should decode it first to a `php-array` and then parse it.

Try this code:

```
$items = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true)['rows'][0];
foreach ($items['elements'] as $key => $item) {
    echo $item['duration']['text'] . ': '; 
    echo $item['duration']['value'] . '<br>';   
}
```